# Ember binding properties to adjacent items in arraycontroller

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to ember and am still getting my sealegs under me with the framework. So far I think its great, except there is one thing that I can't seem to figure out: how to bind a property of an array item to a property of an adjacent array item.

Details:

My model is like so:

```
App.SRDate = Ember.Object.extend({
    timeValue: null,
    reductionAmount: null,
    id: null,
    index: null,
    date: Ember.computed(function(){return formatted date as a string}).property('timeValue') ,
    previousDate: ???
});
```

And I have a simple arraycontroller that just holds a list of the above objects.  What I am trying to do is be able to call `App.dates.objectAt(1).get('previousDate')` and have it return `App.dates.objectAt(0).get('date')`.  I got it to kind of work initially by using a computed property for the previousDate, but it would only update when I changed an item in bound object (i.e. if I changed the date for object 0 it wouldn't update in previousDate for object 1 until I changed the date in object 1, which caused ember to re-evaluate the computed property). If there is a way to define what objects a computed properties are associated with, then that would probably do the trick, however I don't think that is what computed properties are really supposed to be used for...

I also tried a binding like:

```
previousDateBinding: 'App.dates.getObject('+this.get('index')-1+').date'
```

but that didn't work either.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Could you provide more details as to what you're trying to do that requires you do this?

Comment: Ya I'm working on a score system for an online testing platform.  Basically it is to allow a professor to set it up so that students can take a test for a certain amount of time for full credit, then be able to take it for a amount of time for 80%, then an amount of time for 60% etc.  The previousDate reference above will be used in the ui for this, so it will basically say: "From {{previousDate}} to {{date}} remove {{reductionAmount}} points".  I can probably use some sort of view helper to perform the same action, but initially figured it might be easier to do it this way.Thanks for the help

Comment: Also on the first item in the array, previous date would return the final day to get full credit.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you should create intermediate objects that have the properties you'll be outputting rather than trying to do this in your controller.

Comment: Would that break the live binding?  or is their a way to make an object with parameters like  `dateBinding: 'App.objectAt(1).date', previousDateBinding: 'App.dates.objectAt(0).date'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a similar problem, here's how I solved it: http://jsfiddle.net/aMQU6/1/

In my ArrayController, I have a function that observes changes to my content. Then once it is added, I set a property in the new object to be the previous object, then bind the previous object's date to the previousDate property in the added object.

Hope this helped! Let me know if you have any questions.